# Estimating 15 parameters with the least square method for a non-linear objective function MATLAB

Tags: matlab, parameters, least-squares, nonlinear-optimization, nonlinear-functions

I want to estimate the parameters x1-x15 with the least square method in MATLAB. My objective function is

```
sum((Pot-Potcap).^2)
Pot = x(14)*exp(-(t*log(x(1)*x(15) + 1))/x(15)) + x(14)*(exp(-(t*log(x(3)*x(15) + 1))/x(15)) + (x(7)*exp(-(t*log(x(2)*x(15) + 1))/x(15)))/(x(2) - x(3)) + (x(6)*x(7)*exp(-(t*log(x(1)*x(15) + 1))/x(15)))/((x(1) - x(3))*(x(2) - x(3)))) + x(14)*(exp(-(t*log(x(4)*x(15) + 1))/x(15)) + (x(8)*exp(-(t*log(x(3)*x(15) + 1))/x(15)))/(x(3) - x(4)) + (x(7)*x(8)*exp(-(t*log(x(2)*x(15) + 1))/x(15)))/((x(2) - x(4))*(x(3) - x(4))) + (x(6)*x(7)*x(8)*exp(-(t*log(x(1)*x(15) + 1))/x(15)))/((x(1) - x(4))*(x(2) - x(4))*(x(3) - x(4)))) - x(13)*(exp(-(t*log(x(4)*x(15) + 1))/x(15)) + (x(8)*exp(-(t*log(x(3)*x(15) + 1))/x(15)))/(x(4) - x(5)) + (x(7)*x(8)*exp(-(t*log(x(2)*x(15) + 1))/x(15)))/((x(3) - x(5))*(x(4) - x(5))) + (x(6)*x(7)*x(8)*exp(-(t*log(x(1)*x(15) + 1))/x(15)))/((x(2) - x(5))*(x(3) - x(5))*(x(4) - x(5)))) - x(11)*((exp(-(t*log(x(2)*x(15) + 1))/x(15))*(x(2) - x(3))*(x(2) - x(5)))/(x(9)*(x(3) - x(4))) + (x(6)*exp(-(t*log(x(1)*x(15) + 1))/x(15))*(x(1) - x(3))*(x(1) - x(5)))/(x(9)*(x(2) - x(4))*(x(3) - x(4)))) + x(14)*(exp(-(t*log(x(2)*x(15) + 1))/x(15)) + (x(6)*exp(-(t*log(x(1)*x(15) + 1))/x(15)))/(x(1) - x(2))) + x(12)*((exp(-(t*log(x(3)*x(15) + 1))/x(15))*(x(3) - x(4))*(x(3) - x(5)))/(x(8)*x(9)) + (x(7)*exp(-(t*log(x(2)*x(15) + 1))/x(15))*(x(2) - x(4))*(x(2) - x(5)))/(x(8)*x(9)*(x(2) - x(3))) + (x(6)*x(7)*exp(-(t*log(x(1)*x(15) + 1))/x(15))*(x(1) - x(4))*(x(1) - x(5)))/(x(8)*x(9)*(x(1) - x(3))*(x(2) - x(3)))) - x(13)*((exp(-(t*log(x(4)*x(15) + 1))/x(15))*(x(4) - x(5)))/x(9) + (x(8)*exp(-(t*log(x(3)*x(15) + 1))/x(15))*(x(3) - x(5)))/(x(9)*(x(3) - x(4))) + (x(7)*x(8)*exp(-(t*log(x(2)*x(15) + 1))/x(15))*(x(2) - x(5)))/(x(9)*(x(2) - x(4))*(x(3) - x(4))) + (x(6)*x(7)*x(8)*exp(-(t*log(x(1)*x(15) + 1))/x(15))*(x(1) - x(5)))/(x(9)*(x(1) - x(4))*(x(2) - x(4))*(x(3) - x(4)))) + x(12)*((exp(-(t*log(x(3)*x(15) + 1))/x(15))*(x(3) - x(4)))/(x(4) - x(5)) + (x(7)*exp(-(t*log(x(2)*x(15) + 1))/x(15))*(x(2) - x(4)))/((x(3) - x(5))*(x(4) - x(5))) + (x(6)*x(7)*exp(-(t*log(x(1)*x(15) + 1))/x(15))*(x(1) - x(4)))/((x(2) - x(5))*(x(3) - x(5))*(x(4) - x(5)))) - x(11)*((exp(-(t*log(x(2)*x(15) + 1))/x(15))*(x(2) - x(3))*(x(2) - x(4)))/((x(3) - x(5))*(x(4) - x(5))) + (x(6)*exp(-(t*log(x(1)*x(15) + 1))/x(15))*(x(1) - x(3))*(x(1) - x(4)))/((x(2) - x(5))*(x(3) - x(5))*(x(4) - x(5)))) + x(14)*(exp(-(t*log(x(5)*x(15) + 1))/x(15)) + (x(9)*exp(-(t*log(x(4)*x(15) + 1))/x(15)))/(x(4) - x(5)) + (x(8)*x(9)*exp(-(t*log(x(3)*x(15) + 1))/x(15)))/((x(3) - x(5))*(x(4) - x(5))) + (x(7)*x(8)*x(9)*exp(-(t*log(x(2)*x(15) + 1))/x(15)))/((x(2) - x(5))*(x(3) - x(5))*(x(4) - x(5))) + (x(6)*x(7)*x(8)*x(9)*exp(-(t*log(x(1)*x(15) + 1))/x(15)))/((x(1) - x(5))*(x(2) - x(5))*(x(3) - x(5))*(x(4) - x(5)))) - x(13)*((exp(-(t*log(x(2)*x(15) + 1))/x(15))*(x(2) - x(5)))/x(9) + (x(6)*exp(-(t*log(x(1)*x(15) + 1))/x(15))*(x(1) - x(5)))/(x(9)*(x(1) - x(2)))) + x(12)*((exp(-(t*log(x(2)*x(15) + 1))/x(15))*(x(2) - x(4))*(x(2) - x(5)))/(x(8)*x(9)) + (x(6)*exp(-(t*log(x(1)*x(15) + 1))/x(15))*(x(1) - x(4))*(x(1) - x(5)))/(x(8)*x(9)*(x(1) - x(2)))) - x(11)*((exp(-(t*log(x(2)*x(15) + 1))/x(15))*(x(2) - x(4))*(x(2) - x(5)))/(x(8)*x(9)) + (x(6)*exp(-(t*log(x(1)*x(15) + 1))/x(15))*(x(1) - x(4))*(x(1) - x(5)))/(x(8)*x(9)*(x(2) - x(3)))) - x(11)*((exp(-(t*log(x(2)*x(15) + 1))/x(15))*(x(2) - x(3))*(x(2) - x(4))*(x(2) - x(5)))/(x(7)*x(8)*x(9)) + (x(6)*exp(-(t*log(x(1)*x(15) + 1))/x(15))*(x(1) - x(3))*(x(1) - x(4))*(x(1) - x(5)))/(x(7)*x(8)*x(9)*(x(1) - x(2)))) - x(13)*((exp(-(t*log(x(3)*x(15) + 1))/x(15))*(x(3) - x(5)))/x(9) + (x(7)*exp(-(t*log(x(2)*x(15) + 1))/x(15))*(x(2) - x(5)))/(x(9)*(x(2) - x(3))) + (x(6)*x(7)*exp(-(t*log(x(1)*x(15) + 1))/x(15))*(x(1) - x(5)))/(x(9)*(x(1) - x(3))*(x(2) - x(3)))) + x(12)*((exp(-(t*log(x(3)*x(15) + 1))/x(15))*(x(3) - x(5)))/x(9) + (x(7)*exp(-(t*log(x(2)*x(15) + 1))/x(15))*(x(2) - x(5)))/(x(9)*(x(3) - x(4))) + (x(6)*x(7)*exp(-(t*log(x(1)*x(15) + 1))/x(15))*(x(1) - x(5)))/(x(9)*(x(2) - x(4))*(x(3) - x(4)))) - (x(13)*exp(-(t*log(x(1)*x(15) + 1))/x(15))*(x(1) - x(5)))/x(9) + (x(12)*exp(-(t*log(x(1)*x(15) + 1))/x(15))*(x(1) - x(4))*(x(1) - x(5)))/(x(8)*x(9)) + (x(10)*exp(-(t*log(x(1)*x(15) + 1))/x(15))*(x(1) - x(2))*(x(1) - x(3))*(x(1) - x(5)))/(x(9)*(x(2) - x(4))*(x(3) - x(4))) + (x(10)*exp(-(t*log(x(1)*x(15) + 1))/x(15))*(x(1) - x(2))*(x(1) - x(3))*(x(1) - x(4)))/((x(2) - x(5))*(x(3) - x(5))*(x(4) - x(5))) + (x(10)*exp(-(t*log(x(1)*x(15) + 1))/x(15))*(x(1) - x(3))*(x(1) - x(4))*(x(1) - x(5)))/(x(7)*x(8)*x(9)) - (x(11)*exp(-(t*log(x(1)*x(15) + 1))/x(15))*(x(1) - x(3))*(x(1) - x(4))*(x(1) - x(5)))/(x(7)*x(8)*x(9)) + (x(10)*exp(-(t*log(x(1)*x(15) + 1))/x(15))*(x(1) - x(2))*(x(1) - x(4))*(x(1) - x(5)))/(x(8)*x(9)*(x(2) - x(3))) + (x(10)*exp(-(t*log(x(1)*x(15) + 1))/x(15))*(x(1) - x(2))*(x(1) - x(3))*(x(1) - x(4))*(x(1) - x(5)))/(x(6)*x(7)*x(8)*x(9))
```

for the data Potcap and t from 1 to 21. I have tried using the code:

```
x = sym('x', [1 15], 'real')
t = [1;2;3;4;5;6;7;8;9;10;11;12;13;14;15;16;17;18;19;20;21]
x0 = [0.2;0.21;0.22;0.23;0.24;0.31;0.32;0.33;0.34;0.1;0.1;0.1;0.1;0.1;0.3]
lb = zeros(21,1)
ub = [Inf Inf Inf Inf Inf Inf Inf Inf Inf 1 1 1 1 1 Inf]
fnc = @(x) Fungsi(x,t,Potcap);
[p,fval] = fmincon(fnc,x0,[],[],[],[],lb,ub,@mycon)
function f = Fungsi(x, t, Potcap)
   f = sum(((x(14)*exp(-(t.*log(x(1)*x(15) + 1))/x(15)) + x(14)*(exp(-(t.*log(x(3)*x(15) + 1))/x(15)) + (x(7)*exp(-(t.*log(x(2)*x(15) + 1))/x(15)))/(x(2) - x(3)) + (x(6)*x(7)*exp(-(t.*log(x(1)*x(15) + 1))/x(15)))/((x(1) - x(3))*(x(2) - x(3)))) + x(14)*(exp(-(t.*log(x(4)*x(15) + 1))/x(15)) + (x(8)*exp(-(t.*log(x(3)*x(15) + 1))/x(15)))/(x(3) - x(4)) + (x(7)*x(8)*exp(-(t.*log(x(2)*x(15) + 1))/x(15)))/((x(2) - x(4))*(x(3) - x(4))) + (x(6)*x(7)*x(8)*exp(-(t.*log(x(1)*x(15) + 1))/x(15)))/((x(1) - x(4))*(x(2) - x(4))*(x(3) - x(4)))) - x(13)*(exp(-(t.*log(x(4)*x(15) + 1))/x(15)) + (x(8)*exp(-(t.*log(x(3)*x(15) + 1))/x(15)))/(x(4) - x(5)) + (x(7)*x(8)*exp(-(t.*log(x(2)*x(15) + 1))/x(15)))/((x(3) - x(5))*(x(4) - x(5))) + (x(6)*x(7)*x(8)*exp(-(t.*log(x(1)*x(15) + 1))/x(15)))/((x(2) - x(5))*(x(3) - x(5))*(x(4) - x(5)))) - x(11)*((exp(-(t.*log(x(2)*x(15) + 1))/x(15))*(x(2) - x(3))*(x(2) - x(5)))/(x(9)*(x(3) - x(4))) + (x(6)*exp(-(t.*log(x(1)*x(15) + 1))/x(15))*(x(1) - x(3))*(x(1) - x(5)))/(x(9)*(x(2) - x(4))*(x(3) - x(4)))) + x(14)*(exp(-(t.*log(x(2)*x(15) + 1))/x(15)) + (x(6)*exp(-(t.*log(x(1)*x(15) + 1))/x(15)))/(x(1) - x(2))) + x(12)*((exp(-(t.*log(x(3)*x(15) + 1))/x(15))*(x(3) - x(4))*(x(3) - x(5)))/(x(8)*x(9)) + (x(7)*exp(-(t.*log(x(2)*x(15) + 1))/x(15))*(x(2) - x(4))*(x(2) - x(5)))/(x(8)*x(9)*(x(2) - x(3))) + (x(6)*x(7)*exp(-(t.*log(x(1)*x(15) + 1))/x(15))*(x(1) - x(4))*(x(1) - x(5)))/(x(8)*x(9)*(x(1) - x(3))*(x(2) - x(3)))) - x(13)*((exp(-(t.*log(x(4)*x(15) + 1))/x(15))*(x(4) - x(5)))/x(9) + (x(8)*exp(-(t.*log(x(3)*x(15) + 1))/x(15))*(x(3) - x(5)))/(x(9)*(x(3) - x(4))) + (x(7)*x(8)*exp(-(t.*log(x(2)*x(15) + 1))/x(15))*(x(2) - x(5)))/(x(9)*(x(2) - x(4))*(x(3) - x(4))) + (x(6)*x(7)*x(8)*exp(-(t.*log(x(1)*x(15) + 1))/x(15))*(x(1) - x(5)))/(x(9)*(x(1) - x(4))*(x(2) - x(4))*(x(3) - x(4)))) + x(12)*((exp(-(t.*log(x(3)*x(15) + 1))/x(15))*(x(3) - x(4)))/(x(4) - x(5)) + (x(7)*exp(-(t.*log(x(2)*x(15) + 1))/x(15))*(x(2) - x(4)))/((x(3) - x(5))*(x(4) - x(5))) + (x(6)*x(7)*exp(-(t.*log(x(1)*x(15) + 1))/x(15))*(x(1) - x(4)))/((x(2) - x(5))*(x(3) - x(5))*(x(4) - x(5)))) - x(11)*((exp(-(t.*log(x(2)*x(15) + 1))/x(15))*(x(2) - x(3))*(x(2) - x(4)))/((x(3) - x(5))*(x(4) - x(5))) + (x(6)*exp(-(t.*log(x(1)*x(15) + 1))/x(15))*(x(1) - x(3))*(x(1) - x(4)))/((x(2) - x(5))*(x(3) - x(5))*(x(4) - x(5)))) + x(14)*(exp(-(t.*log(x(5)*x(15) + 1))/x(15)) + (x(9)*exp(-(t.*log(x(4)*x(15) + 1))/x(15)))/(x(4) - x(5)) + (x(8)*x(9)*exp(-(t.*log(x(3)*x(15) + 1))/x(15)))/((x(3) - x(5))*(x(4) - x(5))) + (x(7)*x(8)*x(9)*exp(-(t.*log(x(2)*x(15) + 1))/x(15)))/((x(2) - x(5))*(x(3) - x(5))*(x(4) - x(5))) + (x(6)*x(7)*x(8)*x(9)*exp(-(t.*log(x(1)*x(15) + 1))/x(15)))/((x(1) - x(5))*(x(2) - x(5))*(x(3) - x(5))*(x(4) - x(5)))) - x(13)*((exp(-(t.*log(x(2)*x(15) + 1))/x(15))*(x(2) - x(5)))/x(9) + (x(6)*exp(-(t.*log(x(1)*x(15) + 1))/x(15))*(x(1) - x(5)))/(x(9)*(x(1) - x(2)))) + x(12)*((exp(-(t.*log(x(2)*x(15) + 1))/x(15))*(x(2) - x(4))*(x(2) - x(5)))/(x(8)*x(9)) + (x(6)*exp(-(t.*log(x(1)*x(15) + 1))/x(15))*(x(1) - x(4))*(x(1) - x(5)))/(x(8)*x(9)*(x(1) - x(2)))) - x(11)*((exp(-(t.*log(x(2)*x(15) + 1))/x(15))*(x(2) - x(4))*(x(2) - x(5)))/(x(8)*x(9)) + (x(6)*exp(-(t.*log(x(1)*x(15) + 1))/x(15))*(x(1) - x(4))*(x(1) - x(5)))/(x(8)*x(9)*(x(2) - x(3)))) - x(11)*((exp(-(t.*log(x(2)*x(15) + 1))/x(15))*(x(2) - x(3))*(x(2) - x(4))*(x(2) - x(5)))/(x(7)*x(8)*x(9)) + (x(6)*exp(-(t.*log(x(1)*x(15) + 1))/x(15))*(x(1) - x(3))*(x(1) - x(4))*(x(1) - x(5)))/(x(7)*x(8)*x(9)*(x(1) - x(2)))) - x(13)*((exp(-(t.*log(x(3)*x(15) + 1))/x(15))*(x(3) - x(5)))/x(9) + (x(7)*exp(-(t.*log(x(2)*x(15) + 1))/x(15))*(x(2) - x(5)))/(x(9)*(x(2) - x(3))) + (x(6)*x(7)*exp(-(t.*log(x(1)*x(15) + 1))/x(15))*(x(1) - x(5)))/(x(9)*(x(1) - x(3))*(x(2) - x(3)))) + x(12)*((exp(-(t.*log(x(3)*x(15) + 1))/x(15))*(x(3) - x(5)))/x(9) + (x(7)*exp(-(t.*log(x(2)*x(15) + 1))/x(15))*(x(2) - x(5)))/(x(9)*(x(3) - x(4))) + (x(6)*x(7)*exp(-(t.*log(x(1)*x(15) + 1))/x(15))*(x(1) - x(5)))/(x(9)*(x(2) - x(4))*(x(3) - x(4)))) - (x(13)*exp(-(t.*log(x(1)*x(15) + 1))/x(15))*(x(1) - x(5)))/x(9) + (x(12)*exp(-(t.*log(x(1)*x(15) + 1))/x(15))*(x(1) - x(4))*(x(1) - x(5)))/(x(8)*x(9)) + (x(10)*exp(-(t.*log(x(1)*x(15) + 1))/x(15))*(x(1) - x(2))*(x(1) - x(3))*(x(1) - x(5)))/(x(9)*(x(2) - x(4))*(x(3) - x(4))) + (x(10)*exp(-(t.*log(x(1)*x(15) + 1))/x(15))*(x(1) - x(2))*(x(1) - x(3))*(x(1) - x(4)))/((x(2) - x(5))*(x(3) - x(5))*(x(4) - x(5))) + (x(10)*exp(-(t.*log(x(1)*x(15) + 1))/x(15))*(x(1) - x(3))*(x(1) - x(4))*(x(1) - x(5)))/(x(7)*x(8)*x(9)) - (x(11)*exp(-(t.*log(x(1)*x(15) + 1))/x(15))*(x(1) - x(3))*(x(1) - x(4))*(x(1) - x(5)))/(x(7)*x(8)*x(9)) + (x(10)*exp(-(t.*log(x(1)*x(15) + 1))/x(15))*(x(1) - x(2))*(x(1) - x(4))*(x(1) - x(5)))/(x(8)*x(9)*(x(2) - x(3))) + (x(10)*exp(-(t.*log(x(1)*x(15) + 1))/x(15))*(x(1) - x(2))*(x(1) - x(3))*(x(1) - x(4))*(x(1) - x(5)))/(x(6)*x(7)*x(8)*x(9)))-Potcap).^2);
end
function [c,ceq] = mycon(x)
   c = []
   ceq = (x(10)+x(11)+x(12)+x(13)+x(14))==1
end
```

But running the code above meets an error saying "FMINCON requires all values returned by
functions to be of data type double". I have tried many things to fix this error but it still persists. Any suggestions for the problem I have or alternatives to using the code above? Thanks.

**Edit**
The code works by fixing the mistake in syntax for ceq so function @mycon reads as:

```
function [c,ceq] = mycon(x)
   c = [];
   ceq = (x(10)+x(11)+x(12)+x(13)+x(14))-1;
end
```

But now the problem is the outcome is unexpectedly large. MATLAB also prints:

```
Warning: Matrix is close to singular or badly scaled. Results may be inaccurate. RCOND =  3.715224e-17.
```

Any ideas on how to fix this?

Comment: The problem was in ceq so just fixing the syntax for mycon(x) with:

Comment: You need to specify what you mean by 'outcome'. You should also use the debugger to step through your code so that you know where the warning is coming from. It isn't really clear what you're asking.